# Create table using a python dataframe into Postgres SQL on redshift via python sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I want to create a table in Redshift. My password for host is : michael@144 . I cant change this password as it has a lot of protocols involved so when I am trying to create and connect the engine, I am getting the error. I think the error is due to "@" in my password which is interfering with the usual syntax of create engine

Following is the code piece I am using :

```
engine =
sal.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://mike:michael@144@server_name:5112/database_name')

Error : could not translate host name "144@server_name" to address: Unknown server error
```

Problem is multiple "@" character in the syntax. How should I write the syntax so it can connect me to my server

Comment: I am also in a similar situation. Did u manage to resolve this issue?
I tried with this string formatter, still didn't work,
`create_engine( "postgresql:// {username}: {password} @ {hostname}/ {db_name}". format(username=settings.POSTGRES_USERNAME, password=settings.POSTGRES_PASSWORD, hostname=settings.POSTGRES_HOSTNAME, db_name=settings.POSTGRES_DB),`

Answer (score 0):

Initially, I tired using string formatting but didn't work,

`create_engine( "postgresql:// {username}: {password} @ {hostname}/ {db_name}". format(username=settings.POSTGRES_USERNAME, password=settings.POSTGRES_PASSWORD, hostname=settings.POSTGRES_HOSTNAME, db_name=settings.POSTGRES_DB),`

But changing `@` to `%40` seems to have worked.
eg:
`create_engine( "postgresql://username:p%40ssword@hostname/db_name"`

for passsword `p@ssword` to `p%40word`